# TRIGGER AFTER INSERT

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, postgresql, trigger

Estoy intentado migrar scripts de MySQL a PostgresSQL

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_user_role
AFTER INSERT ON sec_user
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO sec_user_sec_role (sec_role_id, sec_user_id) VALUES(2, NEW.id);
END$$
```

Al intentar el trigger anterior me manda el siguiente error:
**ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «INSERT»
LINE 4: INSERT INTO sec_user_sec_role (sec_role_id, sec_user_id) VAL...
^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 68**

Investigue la sintaxis de PostgresSQL pero soy primerizo en ello

```
CREATE TRIGGER nombre { BEFORE | AFTER } { INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE [ OR ... ] }
    ON tabla [ FOR [ EACH ] { ROW | STATEMENT } ]
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE nombre de funcion ( argumentos )
```

La idea en si del disparador es que cada que se almacene un nuevo usuario (en la tabla sec_user) se guarde su id en la tabla sec_user_sec_role (tabla intermedia) con el valor por default de sec_role_id= 2 y el id del usuario recién registrado

Comment: En PostgreSQL no puedes ejecutar sentencias dentro del `TRIGGER`, tienes que crear una función que haga la operación y llamarla desde el `TRIGGER`: *«PostgreSQL only allows the execution of a user-defined function for the triggered action. The standard allows the execution of a number of other SQL commands, such as CREATE TABLE, as the triggered action. This limitation is not hard to work around by creating a user-defined function that executes the desired commands.»*. [Revisa la documentación](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/creating-first-trigger-postgresql/) y los ejemplos que allí hay.

Comment: Exactamente crea una función y posteriormente a eso crea un TRIGGER para mandarla a llamar con las características que ahí pusiste.